# Direction of the angular velocity vector

Tags: vectors

I have to solve the following question:

What is the direction of an angular velocity vector?

What should I look for in order to find this? Is there any known formula for counting this or any general rule that applies?

Comment: What is the setting here? Please add a bit more details. For example is his a high school physics 2D problem, or a general 3D rigid body problem. What is known or given to begin with? Is this a UK based setting using the _left-hand-rule_, or is the standard _right-hand-rule_ convention applies? Please [edit] the question to add the details, not in the comments.

Comment: JAlex "Is this a UK based setting using the left-hand-rule[?]" I'm UK-based and haven't come across a left hand rule in this context. What, I wonder, did you have in mind?

Comment: @PhilipWood I took GCSEs 30 years ago which used LH rule. My info might be outdated!

Comment: Ah yes, Fleming's left hand motor rule. I thought you might have had that in mind. It's got to be the left hand so that the fingers can stand for First: Field, seCond: Current, Thumb: Thrust and roughly the same correspondence (but with Motion instead of Thrust) can be used with the right hand for currents due to motional emfs. The rules don't aid understanding of what's going on, but they're not designed for physicists; Fleming was an electrical engineer and the rules are excellent for practical work with motors and generators.

Answer (score 2):

The angular velocity is defined as

$$\vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{r} \times \vec{v}}{|\vec{r}|^2}$$

where $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ are displacement and velocity vectors, respectively, and $|\vec{r}|$ is the displacement vector magnitude (length). I leave it to you to figure out the direction of $\vec{\omega}$.

If you are not sure how to proceed, study *vector cross product* and the *right hand rule*.

Answer (score 0):

Since the velocity vector for each particle in a rotating system has a different magnitude and direction, it was decided that the vector representing the rotation of the system as a whole would be chosen in the one direction which is usually fixed; along the the axis of rotation. That leaves the question: which direction along the axis? The definition for the resultant of a vector product (r x v)  comes with a right hand rule. The form of the rule that I find easiest to remember is this: Hold your right hand so that you can bend your fingers from the direction of the first named vector in the product to the direction of the second named vector.  Your thumb gives the direction for the product.  Or in this case, if you wrap your right hand fingers around the axle in  the direction of motion, your thumb gives the direction for the angular velocity vector along the axle.  (This also applies to the vectors for angular displacement and angular acceleration.)